# Fatal Exception: AsyncTask #1

Tags: exception, task

I have a Fatal Exception: AsyncTask #1 in the following part, but dont know why.

```
    /**
     * getting Charts from URL
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_read, "POST", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON response
        Log.d("Charts: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products

                JSONArray charts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CHARTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for(int i=0;i<charts.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = charts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = json_data.getString("id");
                    String interpret = json_data.getString("interpret");
                    String titel = json_data.getString("titel");
                    String album = json_data.getString("album");
                    String albumcover = json_data.getString("albumcover");
                    String likes = json_data.getString("likes");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_INTERPRET, interpret);
                    map.put(TAG_TITEL, titel);
                    map.put(TAG_ALBUM, album);
                    map.put(TAG_ALBUMCOVER, albumcover);
                    map.put(TAG_LIKES, likes);       

                    songslist.add(map);

                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        CreateSong.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            } 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This is my first question. Hope you know what to do. I get the data from a Database and put them into a JSON Array and then into a Hashmap, but it seems that the error comes by the JSON.

EDIT: LOG CAT

```
07-11 23:20:48.320: D/CLIPBOARD(13241): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
07-11 23:20:52.510: D/dalvikvm(13241): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 139K, 3% free 9004K/9223K, paused 13ms
07-11 23:20:52.650: E/JSON Parser(13241): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
07-11 23:20:52.650: W/dalvikvm(13241): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c331f8)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at de.andreasgloeckner.ShowCharts$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(ShowCharts.java:172)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at     de.andreasgloeckner.ShowCharts$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(ShowCharts.java:1)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: You need to share the exception stacktrace and the output from logcat. That's the authority :). Everything else would be a guess.

Comment: Srsly, i have some Problems with this Site...whats the best possibility to add the log cat? When i edit my post, it looks strange as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException in your code (ShowCharts.java, line 172). Now figure out which line is that . You are accessing on a null object obviously or just share line 172 here. It could be `songslist` object. I don't see initialization in the code block you shared.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-11 23:20:52.675: E/AndroidRuntime(13241):    at de.andreasgloeckner.ShowCharts$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(ShowCharts.java:172)
```

Answer (score 0):

from inside the doInBackground method , you cant change or touch any UI element , so you cant call another activity , what you have to do is to call the another activity from inside the onPostExecute method from your Asynctask